# How to get text from a read only text box in protractor when getText() returns object as promise

Tags: protractor

I want to get the value from the text box.

using method like:

```
element(by.xpath('//*[id="answer_1_total"]')).getText().then(function(text){
     var value=text.toString();
     console.log(value);
});
```

element contains numeric value. The same lines of code I have applied for button and it was working fine.

When I am executing this, nothing is getting displayed so my understanding is that this lines are not getting executed.

Note: instead of `getText()`, I have tried `getAttribute('value')` but no success.

Please help as I am sticking at this point from past 2 days.

Comment: have you tried just printing the text? are you getting numerical value?

Comment: and why are you converting text to string, it is already a string.if you want to convert to number you should use parseInt function.

Comment: can you post the HTML code also

Comment: Hi igniteram1, i tried to print the value it is coming as string but when i m trying to print direct getText() value then i m getting below text..

Answer (score 0):

print only *`getText()`* value

```
actionResults_:
 { closure_uid_189613320: 1023,

   parent_: [Object],
   callbacks_: null,
   state_: 'pending',
   handled_: false,
   pendingNotifications_: false,
   value_: undefined },
locator_: { using: 'id', value: 'currencysumDisplay_1_answer' },
click: [Function],
sendKeys: [Function],

getText: [Function],

isDisplayed: [Function],
getId: [Function],
getRawId: [Function] },
```

click: [Function],`enter code here`
 sendKeys: [Function],
 getText: [Function],

This is the `getText()` value and if i m trying to change it to `toString()` then it is showing `[object Object]` in console

Answer (score 0):

According to your answer (that is actually not an answer), you are trying to print out an *`ElementFinder` instance string representation* on the console. Instead, print an actual value of the text resolved from `getText()` promise:

```
element(by.xpath('//*[id="answer_1_total"]')).getText().then(function(text) {
    console.log(text);
});
```

Or, a short version:

```
element(by.xpath('//*[id="answer_1_total"]')).getText().then(console.log);
```